# How can a service shorten a password if it is not stored in plaintext?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can Microsoft validate a shorter password on Microsoft accounts (MSDN)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19028/how-can-microsoft-validate-a-shorter-password-on-microsoft-accounts-msdn)

My Microsoft password was 18 characters long and when I updated to Outlook.com it started to ask me to enter my current password but the first 16 characters only.

How can they check if my password is correct by shortening it without storing it as plaintext?